# Importing electron conditionally into react-native-web app

Tags: javascript, react-native, electron, electron-builder, react-native-web

I currently have a `react-native-web` app that targets both Android and Electron.

I've added electron shortcuts into the app and I'm using the `ipcRenderer` in react components to listen to accelerators and run react-specific code.

The problem is, unless I am importing the `ipcRenderer` into a `.web.js` file I receive the following error when running Android:

```
Unable to resolve module `fs` from `/Users/.../node_modules/electron/index.js`: Module `fs` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

Snippet of code causing the problem:

```
if (isElectron()) {
    const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron'); <-- this line
```

I've tried wrapping the import in a `Platform.OS` conditional like so

```
if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
    const isElectron = require('is-electron');

    if (isElectron()) {
        const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
```

However I still receive the same error.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem :)

I made 2 files

`ipcRenderer.js` containing an export of a null object

and `ipcRenderer.web.js` which contained the `isElectron()` check and either exported a null or the `ipcRenderer` from electron